# Piranha CMS Creating Region Extension

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5.1, piranha-cms

I'm trying to create a new region extension in piranha CMS.

Long term it will be more complicated but initially to get it working I want the tabcontainer to be a list of HTML Regions so that I can use it to populate a tab container. This is my TabContainer class and view

**TabContainer.cs**

```
[Export(typeof(IExtension))]
[ExportMetadata("InternalId", "TabContainer")]
[ExportMetadata("Name", "Tab Region")]
[ExportMetadata("Type", ExtensionType.Region)]
[Serializable]
public class TabContainer : IExtension
{
    public IList<HtmlRegion> Items { get; set; }

    public TabContainer()
    {
        Items = new List<HtmlRegion>();
    }

    public virtual void Ensure(DataContext db) { }
    public virtual void Init(object model) { }
    public virtual void OnManagerSave(object model) { }
    public virtual void OnManagerDelete(object model) { }

    public void Ensure(object model) {}

    public virtual void InitManager(object model)
    {
    }

    public virtual object GetContent(object model)
    {
        return this;
    }
```

**TabContainer.cshtml**

```
@model MatchtechGroup.PiranhaExtensions.Regions.TabContainer

<ul class="form">

</ul>
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Items)
```

The manager recognises my new Region and I've been able to add it to my start page, I'm unsure about how to initialise the manager, so that I can add and remove HTMLRegions in the list and how to retrieve them from the DB when already saved.

How do I include an add button (similar to the attachments tab) so that I can add items via the manager interface?

If there's a better approach to having a list based page with the built in components i'm open to suggestions, but I'm a little bit stuck.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There's no good support in the core framework for managing a region with multiple values, like the sortable list of attachments. I've done a number of quick implementations of it in different projects but they have all relied on a lot of client-side javascript for creating the new regions which is a rather poor solution since it requires duplication of logic.

This is however a feature that I've tried implementing and which is desired for an upcoming version. If you're interested I could always set up a GitHub repo for collaboration where we could implement this as an add-on module until it is included in the core. Would you be interested in this?

Regards

Håkan

Comment: Hi, definitely would be interested in collaborating on something like this. It's something for us that in key in being able to use Piranha CMS across the rest of the business

Comment: That' great! I'll set up a repo and let you know as soon as I get back from vaccation!

Answer (score 0):

As  Håkan  said

> There's no good support in the core framework for managing a region with multiple values, like the sortable list of attachments.

So this is not the best practice, but it does the trick:

TabRegion.cs:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.Composition;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Web;

namespace Piranha.Extend.Regions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Simple Tab region.
    /// </summary>
    [Export(typeof(IExtension))]
    [ExportMetadata("InternalId", "TabRegion")]
    [ExportMetadata("Name", "TabRegionName")]
    [ExportMetadata("ResourceType", typeof(Resources.Extensions))]
    [ExportMetadata("Type", ExtensionType.Region)]
    [Serializable]
    public class TabRegion :  Extension
    {
        #region Properties
        /// <summary>
        /// Gets/sets the Tab title.
        /// </summary>
        [Display(ResourceType = typeof(Piranha.Resources.Extensions), Name = "TabRegionTitle")]
        public string Title { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets/sets the Tab body.
        /// </summary>
        [Display(ResourceType = typeof(Piranha.Resources.Extensions), Name = "TabRegionBody")]
        public string Body { get; set; }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

TabRegion.cshtml

```
@model Piranha.Extend.Regions.TabRegion
@{
}
<ul class="form">
    <li>@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Title)
        <div class="input">@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Title)</div>
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Title)</li>
    <li>@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Body)
        <div class="input">@Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Body, new { @class = "editor", @rows = 10 })</div>
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Body)</li>
</ul>
```

Finally add this to your view (index.cshtml):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/style.css">
<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#tabs").tabs();
    });
</script>

<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        @foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> regions in Model.Regions)
        {
            if (regions.Value.ToString() == "Piranha.Extend.Regions.TabRegion")
            {
                dynamic tab = regions.Value;
                if (tab.Title !=null)
                {
                    <li> <a href="#tabs-@regions.Key">@tab.Title</a></li>
                }
            }
        }
    </ul>
    @foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> regions in Model.Regions)
    {
        if (regions.Value.ToString() == "Piranha.Extend.Regions.TabRegion")
        {
            dynamic tab = regions.Value;
            if (tab.Title != null)
            {
                <div id="tabs-@regions.Key">
                    @Html.Raw(@tab.Body)
                </div>}
        }
    }
</div>
```